# VBA in Word look for a word in tables and if found copy the row

Tags: excel, datatable, ms-word, find, cell

I need help writing a code that looks for a word in multiple tables in a Word file. If the word is found in the cell, I want to copy the row and paste it into an Excel file.

One challenge I have are the vertically merged cells. How could I overcome this?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.